# VBA Loop to next row and highligth the Error in the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been using the below code which I have got from one of website, however, the user always tend to forget to check whether the data (IDs) are already sent to the Access Database, is there any way to loop the process and still export the data and change the font color of item not processed and introduce a new column with text "Not Imported"?

```
Sub Export_Data()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim nextrow As Long

'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'On Error Resume Next

'Variables for file path and last row of data
dbPath = ActiveSheet.Range("I3").Value
nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Initialise the collection class variable
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'Check for data
If Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
MsgBox " Add the data that you want to send to MS Access"
Exit Sub
End If

'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
'—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
'two primary providers used in ADO SQLOLEDB —-Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 —-Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
'OLE stands for Object Linking and Embedding, Database

'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
rst.Open Source:="PhoneList", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable

'you now have the recordset object
'add the values to it
For x = 2 To nextrow
rst.AddNew
For i = 1 To 7
rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
Next i
rst.Update
Next x

'close the recordset
rst.Close
' Close the connection
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'communicate with the user
MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"

'Update the sheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'show the next ID
'Sheet1.Range("J3").Value = Sheet1.Range("K3").Value + 1

'Clear the data
'Sheet1.Range("A2:G1000").ClearContents

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:

'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help, as I don't know how to begin with the loop resume next. I hope you guys can help me change or modify this code.

Comment: Hi @Mielkew, I do not understand very well what you wish to do. Could you explain me more so I could assist you please?

Comment: Actually, after following your script, I seem to understand what you wanted to do, so kindly test the code and let me know. Kindly accept the answer as well when it's working for you :)

Comment: Hi @TsiriniainaRakotonirina I tried the code but getting an error "ByRef argument type mismatch", I will assume that the dbPath is not properly declared. I have a another sub to the the filepath of the database Application.GetOpenFilename and placed the value in Sheet1.Range("I3").Value = FName

Comment: kindly try it now. I updated the script. I apologize as I forgot to declare DbPath, nRow and nCol. It should work now :)

Comment: Hi @TsiriniainaRakotonirina, I need to know whether the ID already existing in the AccessDB, if does exist the error should be handled
if error indicate in "H Column" not exported to avoid duplicate entry in the AccessDB then proceed to next row, however, the code I have is currently avoiding to go to next value as it

Comment: so if I understand you well, instead of having the Column H, you prefer to check from the DB if the ID exists already? Isn't it?

Comment: If you wish to do this checking, you need to send me [and update the Question] with a screenshot of your Database Table structure so I could write a Sql Script checking it properly

Comment: Hi @TsiriniainaRakotonirina thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate you looking into this. I have really going to shoot my head now. hehehe How can I share you the file?

Comment: Yes please, you can send me the link (xls & mdb) will give me better precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the Code, I think I finally understood what you wanted to do:

> You wanted to check first if the Row has been exported or not before proceeding

### So here is the updated Script.

1. I changed the sequence of several sections of the code as they were not coherent or will cause you errors.
2. I added a Column H supposing your columns are A to G, where H will store «Exported» after it has been successfully stored on the Database.

So this should work for you now:

### Main Sub Exporting to Access

```
Sub Export_Data_Updated()

Dim dbPath As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim exportedRowCnt As Long

'add error handling
On Error GoTo exitSub

'Check for data
'##> This should be first as it is useless to open cnx or find path/last row if this will exit the sub
    If Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox " Add the data that you want to send to MS Access"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '##> Only Continue when the above is fine

'##> Check if the path exits first
    'Variables for file path
    dbPath = ActiveSheet.Range("J3").Value  '##> This was wrong before pointing to I3

    If Not FileExists(dbPath) Then
        MsgBox "The Database file doesn't exist! Kindly correct first"
            Exit Sub
    End If

'##> Only then that you can proceed
    'find las last row of data
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'##> Change the Error handler now
    Dim cnx As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    'Initialise the collection class variable
    Set cnx = New ADODB.Connection

    'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
    '—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
    'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
    cnx.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
    'two primary providers used in ADO SQLOLEDB —-Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 —-Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
    'OLE stands for Object Linking and Embedding, Database

    'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

    'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
    'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
    rst.Open Source:="PhoneList", ActiveConnection:=cnx, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTable

'##> Continue reading Database now
    'you now have the recordset object
    'add the values to it

    'Wait Cursor
    Application.Cursor = xlWait

    'Pause Screen Update
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '##> Set exportedRowCnt to 0 first
    exportedRowCnt = 0

        '##> Let's suppose Data is on Column A to G.
        '    --> So let's put the "Exported" on Column H
    For nRow = 2 To lastRow
        '##> Check if the Row has already been imported?
        'If it it isn't then continue
        If IdExists(cnx, Range("A" & nRow).Value) Then
            'Item already exported, so update the Status
            Range("H" & nRow).Value2 = "Exported"
        Else
            rst.AddNew  'Add New RecordSet
                'Itirating Columns
                For nCol = 1 To 7
                    rst.Fields(Cells(1, nCol).Value2) = Cells(nRow, nCol).Value 'Using the Excel Sheet Column Heading
                Next nCol

            rst.Update  'Update RecordSet

            '##>Update the Status on Column H when the record is successfully updated
            Range("H" & nRow).Value2 = "Exported"

            'Increment exportedRowCnt
            exportedRowCnt = exportedRowCnt + 1
        End If
    Next nRow

    'close the recordset
    rst.Close

    ' Close the connection
    cnx.Close
    'clear memory
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnx = Nothing

    If exportedRowCnt > 0 Then
        'communicate with the user
        MsgBox exportedRowCnt & " row(s) successfully sent to the access database"
    End If

    'Update the sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
exitSub:
    'Restore Default Cursor
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault

    'Update the sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub

errHandler:
    'clear memory
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnx = Nothing
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"

    Resume exitSub
End Sub
```

### Function Checking if File Exists:

> NB: Now valid ID is only **String Type**

```
Function IdExists(cnx As ADODB.Connection, sId As String) As Boolean

'##> Set IdExists as False and change to true if the ID exists already
    IdExists = False

'##> Change the Error handler now
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command   'dim the ADO command class

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    'Sql For search
    Dim sSql As String
    sSql = "SELECT Count(PhoneList.ID) AS IDCnt FROM PhoneList WHERE (PhoneList.ID='" & sId & "')"

    '##> Execute command and collect it into a Recordset
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx
    cmd.CommandText = sSql

    'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
    Set rst = cmd.Execute 'New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

    'Read First RST
    rst.MoveFirst

'##> If rst returns a value then ID already exists
    If rst.Fields(0) > 0 Then
        IdExists = True
    End If

    'close the recordset
    rst.Close

    'clear memory
    Set rst = Nothing
exitFunction:
        Exit Function

errHandler:
    'clear memory
    Set rst = Nothing
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " :" & Err.Description
End Function
```

> **NB:** Kindly read any comments preceeded by «'##>» as those are principal changes or explanations you need to understand

### Updates:

> Here is the File after the updates: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XqEboSFed_6exDwvBZGOqcZWkN8YaslY

---> Fortunately, you sent me the file as I saw the DbPath was pointing on a wrong cell causing a missing file error. Now all is Fixed and working!

I wish you all the best!

Comment: Hi @Mielkew, you can comment/reply me over here. Let me investigate why that error. Hold on please

Comment: hi @TsiriniainaRakotonirina (https://hbkcrccjv-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/p/edward/Ev_sdY3a4YRIpb2zlHMDUsEBx6nhuxo3QSOvA0-Ui6CiEw?e=saZ6xV), I really appreciate your time looking at this.

Comment: @Mielkew, kindly download the files now and update the Location of the DB and test it. It shall be working fine for you now. Kindly let me know if it is

Comment: Thank you so much @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina, I will try it tomorrow when I get back to office. Stay safe and God bless you.

Comment: No Problem @Mielkew, it's Sabbath tomorrow so I won't connect. See you next week then. Blessings

Comment: Hi @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina I tried the code and work perfectly, but when I change the ID to Alphanumeric I got an error? Error 13 Type Mismatched? I also changed the AccessDB field type to "Short Text" and Function IdExists nId As Long to As String

Comment: Hi @Mielkew, it's normal. Your `ID Field` in the Access Database is of **numeric type**. That's why it only accepts **numeric**.

Comment: But please try the New Code now, especially the Function `IdExists` as it's working for String Type now

Comment: Hi @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina you are life saver. Thank you so much for your help and God Bless you and your family. Stay safe my brother.

Comment: Hi @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina, if it not match to ask, I tried to modify the script to update the existing records in accessdDB by ID, however, I'm not getting anywhere with the script. Should I Ask for a new question in this Forum? (https://hbkcrccjv-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/p/edward/Ev_sdY3a4YRIpb2zlHMDUsEBx6nhuxo3QSOvA0-Ui6CiEw?e=wPjhaf)

Comment: I tested the file you sent me in the Comments, you just need to change this section in the **Export_Data_Updated** script: `dbPath = Worksheets("Export").Range("J3").Value`. What was wrong was the Cell where your Database Path was stored. It is actually on **J3**. Your original Question is solved now so kindly Vote and Select the Answer which helped you the much now! ;)

Comment: For the next issue, you better open a new Thread and give me the link here, I will be happy to assist you in that one as well :)

Comment: Hi @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina Ask New Question on How to update existing records in AccessDB using Excel Values (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169073/updating-records-in-access-table-using-excel-vba)

Comment: Hi @Mielkew, I saw the new Question. But since your original Question here is solved now, kindly (1) Vote and (2) Select the Answer which helped you the much now! ;)

Comment: Hi @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina I think I managed to close and marked this question as solved now. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @Mielkew for accepting the answer. I'll be grateful to you to Vote for it as well please :)

Comment: Hi @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina I think, I already did but somehow my reputation is less than 15 that's why it don't show on the screen? I get this notification " Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Hi @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina I hope you can help me out on the other scripts I posted. Thanks brother..